# Редирект неактивного пользователя на главную страницу

Tags: javascript

Данный код сразу выставляет таймер на 15 секунд и редиректит на главную страницу, как сделать что бы таймер появлялся если пользователь некоторое время в АФК?

```
<b><span id="time"></span></b>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 15;//время в сек.
    function time(){
         document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = i;//визуальный счетчик
         i--;//уменьшение счетчика
         if (i < 0) location.href = "localhost/index.php";//редирект
    }
    time();
    setInterval(time, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Отслеживать изменение положения мыши, например. Если положение не меняется продолжительное время - перенаправление

Comment: на словах это всегда здорово звучит

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так

```
var i = 15,
    timer;//время в сек.
function time(){
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = i;//визуальный счетчик
    i--;//уменьшение счетчика
    if (i < 0) {
        alert('Время кончилось');
        location.href = "/index.php";//редирект            
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}
function reset() {
    i = 15;
    time();
}
time();
timer = setInterval(time, 1000);
document.onmousemove = reset;
document.onkeypress = reset;
```

Answer (score 0):

$(window).on("blur", function() {}); - в случае, если пользователь перешел на другую вкладку, или окно